# Canvas animation eats a lot of GPU memory

Tags: performance, animation, canvas, gpu

I'm building small lib to make myself familiar with canvas and its API. Working version is available on Github:

https://github.com/hinok/wavy-canvas/tree/optimize-perf

and the image below shows the animation

[image: Sample animation produced by wavy-canvas]

I spent last weekend on trying to improve performance of the wavy-canvas. I decreased cpu usage from 50% to ~25% so it's good but the main problem still exists - my fans in laptop are spinning really really loud.

The whole code is available on Github so if someone more experienced with canvas could look at it and show me direction what could be improved, I will be grateful.

**Key facts**

- animation is smooth (using requestAnimationFrame)
- I hit 60 fps even when I set throttling CPU as 5x times slower in Dev Tools
- CPU usage is around 15%-25%, but webpage with demo eats a lot of GPU memory, a lot!

[image: Task manager from Chrome which shows GPU memory usage]

I'm pretty sure that **577 MB** for that kind of simple effect is way too much.

I made a few experiments that don't change performance, one of them:

Using

```
context.globalAlpha
```

instead of

```
context.fillStyle = ...
context.strokeStyle = ...
```

Comment: A game @ 30fps (no idle)  all rendering via drawImage, with heavy use of comp ops. Fan never kicks in. But on the same machine a simple particle demo that does all rendering via the vector calls (`ctx.moveTo`, `lineTo`, `arc`,` fillRect`, etc) It runs at 60fps with idle time ~20% within 30 sec the fan starts, 2min performance takes a hit as OS throttles CPU to keep cool  3-4min Laptop shuts down. Vector calls are CPU renderer GPU assisted, drawImage just GPU. Fullscreen getimageData, process, putImageData, with idle time overheats, fullscreen webGL many layer GPU < 20fps 0 idle not heating.

Comment: Some laptop have two cooling systems one for the CPU and the other for the GPU. You can feel on the top surface the two hot spots and tell which is running hot (GPU or CPU). If you have a integrated GPU/CPU or they share a cooling system you will not be able to know which component is generating the extra heat.

Comment: Just fast read your repo, but one way to improve a bit further your code would be to regroup all your Circles `draw` method in a single one, since it seems thay all have the same fill and stroke styles, so you can do `ctx.strokeStyle=...; ctx.beginPath(); Circles.forEach(c=>{ctx.moveTo(c.x+c.radius, c.y); ctx.arc(...);); ctx.fill(); ctx.stroke();` Doing this, the GPU has only one drawing operation to perform, while in your current operation, it has to perform antialiasing + compo against previous content on each Circle.

Comment: @Kaiido I've done that and it hasn't improved the performance. I know that lineWidth, fillStyle and strokeStyle are called for each frame but I moved them to the setupAnimation() - just one call, even without calculating opacity for each frame and performance has been the same.